# ScrollView start scroll only second time that the view appear

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7

I've a problem with my view in iOS7 with autolayout.

This is my structure:
[image]

The `UITextView` content is dynamic so I fit his `contentSize` dynamically in the `viewDidLoad`.

In my `viewDidAppear` I try to fit the `contentSize` of the MainScroll and the mother view calculated by the sum of `UIScrollView` height (the little one), Pager height and `UITextView` height. I logged this height and it returned the correct size: 1300px but the view doesn't scroll.

If I change tab and return here the scroll start to scroll, I've tried to put every piece of code in the `viewDidLoad` but it doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Thanks and sorry for bad English.

Comment: Have you tried using [scrollView layoutSubviews] or [scrollView setNeedsDisplay]  after you do this?

Comment: I've tried now but it doesn't work.. 
For information: if i remove any subview and only change the contentSize height the behavior is the same. It start scroll only when the viewDidAppear is called for the second time..

Comment: The bigger one, the smaller one works great!

Comment: Just a hunch, can you try putting this in all your views including in the bigger ScrollView: yourViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. :( I don't figured out!

Comment: Did it work before in iOS6?

Comment: I started to develop this app in iOS 7, before in iOS 6 I simply remove the constraint between view (scroll view) and his superview and it works everything.. Now in Xcode 5 the standard constraints are hidden and I figured out how to make the view scroll.. Do you have some sample of a uiviewcontroller with a scroll view as main view?

Comment: Have you tried pressing it, pressing the buttons in the lower right bar, and pressing "reset constraints" or "reset to suggested constraints"

Comment: "reset to suggested constraints" WORKS!!! Thanks AdamG

Comment: AdamG if you reply i can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Let me help here: @AdamG Hey, Adam, he asked if you could post that as answer and he will mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks @Unheilig for your help (about the question and about the comment) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting it and then selecting "reset to suggested constraints" in the storyboard. :).