# Creating UIScrollView in Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I simply have a `ViewController` and added `UIScrollView` into that. Later on I created `UIImageView` which is larger than `UIScrollView` and inserted into the `UIScrollView`.

However when I run the simulator, `UIScrollView` does not scroll. I can bounce it but it does not simply leave it's current position within the `UIImageView`.

I also tried using `[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 640)];` within my viewDidLoad and it did not really work.

So how can I make the `UIScrollView` to actually scroll?
I am using Xcode 5 and iOS 6.1

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809984/designing-inside-a-scrollview-in-xcode-4-2-with-storyboards/9933376#9933376

Comment: I already did the correct answer, that's not solving my problem

Comment: No, I couldn't @AdamG

Answer (score 0):

Set the `contentSize` in `viewDidAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`.  Make sure scrolling enabled is checked in the storyboard under the attributes inspector (select the scroll view and press the shield icon on the right top).

Comment: Is user interaction enabled?

Comment: Actually, try pressing the bounds button while selecting the scrollView and then clicking "reset to suggested bounds".  That has fixed this problem for people in the past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227297/scrollview-start-scroll-only-second-time-that-the-view-appear/19252625#19252625

Comment: Where is bounds button?

Comment: StoryBoard, lower right corner, middle tab icon, press "resolve autolayout issues"

Comment: No, that did not fix too.

I could not find any tutorial for Xcode 5 doing UIScrollView in storyboards. If you have some sort of blog or something could you make a short one and then include your project as well so that people can download and reference it?